# inspecting javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

In PHP I can loop through an array with a foreach as loop to examine the contents of the array

```
$array = array(...);
foreach($array as $K=>$V){
    echo $K." = ".$V;
}
```

I would like to do something similar to inspect my javascript array

```
var array = new Array();
foreach(array ...){
    window.alert(...);
}
```

how can I do this?

**EDIT**

I should have noted that I need both the **keyname** AND the value

**EDIT AGAIN**

```
var $_SESSION = new Array();
$_SESSION['pin'] = "asdf";
$_SESSION['something'] = "1234";
$_SESSION['something_else'] = "123";
```

here's an example of my array^

Comment: Just use a "normal" `for` loop: `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ alert(array[i]); }`

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays".  What *exactly* is it that you have?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I posted an example of what I mean by "Associative array" This is pretty much what I'm working with. I need to window.alert each index with both the keyname and the value.

Comment: That's what you have in PHP!  I was asking what you have in *JavaScript*.  "Associative arrays" *don't exist* in JavaScript (the term is not used in that language).  I'm assuming you have an *object* (which is *not* an array).  Objects and Arrays are handled differently in JavaScript.

Comment: @RocketHazmat no I know $_SESSION is a PHP thing but I'm using as the name of my JS array, as it holds the same data.

Comment: How are you storing that data in JavaScript?  Can you show us that?  I'm fairly certain that the "array" you have is not what you think it is.

Comment: @RocketHazmat the code above is JS not PHP

Comment: Indeed it is (I didn't notice the 1st time), though what you have created is *not* an "associative array".  You have created an array (with 0 elements) in it, then you added 3 properties to it.  This is not the correct way to create the data structure you want.  You want to create an object.  `var $_SESSION = {};  $_SESSION['pin'] = "asdf";` (or `var $_SESSION = {pin: 'asdf'};`).

Comment: it was just an example, I'm working with a javascript "class".. putting "class" in quotes since we're being technical..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you would do something like this:

```
for(var i in array) {
     if(array.hasOwnProperty(i)){
          alert(array[i]);
     }
}
```

EDITED: to check for presence of key in object.

Comment: I wouldn't use `for..in` for arrays.

Comment: Thanks, it's an associative array though. How can I make this work with an associative array?

Comment: @Adelphia: JavaScript doesn't have "associative arrays".

Comment: ok, well how do I get the keyname then? this only shows how to display the value of each index. @RocketHazmat

Comment: sure, if it's an associative array, you coudl do a check like this:if (if  array.hasOwnProperty('key') ) {
    //do this
}

Comment: @Adelphia: The key is `i`.  Can you show us how you're adding elements to `array`.  I don't think you have what you think you have.

Comment: @RocketHazmat To be more precise, JavaScript doesn't have anything but associative arrays.

Comment: @sabof: I understand what you mean, but don't say that.  It's just confusing, and incorrect.  JavaScript has "objects" (which are *not* "associative arrays").

Answer (score 1):

```
function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
}
[2, 5, 9].forEach(logArrayElements);
// logs:
// a[0] = 2
// a[1] = 5
// a[2] = 9
```

(taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

Note that this isn't compatible with IE8 or lower. There simply was no foreach control in older javascript versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var a = 0, b = array.length; a < b; a++) {
    alert(array[a]);
}
```

Defining `b = array.length` speeds up the loop as `a < array.length` would re-check the length of the array on each iteration.

Here's [why you shouldn't use `for ... in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/11047).